# Getting custom attributes for properties in class and SetValue

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am just trying to play around with some things. I made a kind of an OR/M type mapper thing and because I am using reflection, performance is slow. How can I speed this up or use a better and more efficient approach?

I have a custom attribute with a named parameter and allow multiple
I then use Reflection to:

- Get the properties where they contain the custom attribute decoration
- for each property found, get the Custom attributes data
- for each custom attribute data, get the named arguments

Then I check the named argument memberinfo name to see if it matches the named parameter in question for the attribute and if it does, it gets the value set for that named parameter and finally reads data from the dataReader for that named parameter value and uses .SetValue to set the value read from the reader to the property.

Here is some code (not complete in any way) and was hoping someone can tell me how to gain that perf improvement. 
Running it 10,000 times (before this doing an initial call to JIT excersize etc...) gives me these avg times:

3.79ms

doing it the manual way (i.e hardcoded mapping from DB to DTO): 0.05ms

I know this is like "another OR/M" - but it is not quite like that and it is more for my fun than anything.

```
private T Populate<T>(IDataReader reader) where T : class, new()
{ 
   T val = new T();

            if (reader != null && !reader.IsClosed)
            {

                var propsWithSQLColumnNameAttributes = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SQLColumnNameAttribute)) && prop.CanWrite && prop.GetSetMethod() != null);

                foreach (var currentProperty in propsWithSQLColumnNameAttributes)
                {   
                    foreach (var currentAttributeForProperty in currentProperty.GetCustomAttributesData())
                    {
                        string currentAttribParamValue = null;
                        foreach (var currentNamedArgument in currentAttributeForProperty.NamedArguments)
                        {
                            if (String.Equals(currentNamedArgument.MemberInfo.Name, SQLColumnNameAttribute.PropertyNames.DataColumnNamePropertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                currentAttribParamValue = currentNamedArgument.TypedValue.Value == null ? null : currentNamedArgument.TypedValue.Value.ToString();


                                if (reader.DoesFieldExist(currentAttribParamValue))
                                {
                                    var dbRecordValue = reader[currentAttribParamValue] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader[currentAttribParamValue];

                                    currentProperty.SetValue(val, dbRecordValue, null);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return val;
}
```

Not the best of code but regardless, perf is the issue here and would like to know how to improve it, either by using a different approach of reflection or maybe the ordering and kind of algorithm being used is incorrect

Many thanks - I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to gain performance as an academic exercise, or are you actually concerned about the performance? I ask, because if it is the latter, then the answer will be very different ;)

Comment: Thanks Josh! I am concerned about the performance. I want to make it as fast and efficient as possible

Comment: As an example you could check repositories for [dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) or [Sqlfu](https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu/blob/master/src/SqlFu/PocoFactory.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/503527/Reflection-optimization-techniques and see if it helps you. 
It talks about reflection optimization in many scenarios, and once you wanna learn, this could be a great resource.

Comment: Thanks batagliao. It looks interesting but still think it maybe a little too much in terms of excessive code to improve perf. But then I guess sometimes you need to do that. From reading and getting ideas, seems that I may need to create a cache dictionary in the class in question (<T>) and on the constructor, find details about itself and store the propertyName and attribute param values in a dictionary  of some sort however there wouldnt be a way of accessing the cache since T is unknown

Comment: If I understande what you're talking. T could be know as typeof(T), so  the key in you dictionary could be Type. Like Dictionay<Type, TAnother>.

Comment: Thanks batagliao - quite possibly. The problem there then is that bacause the object "Type" is more bloated than some other types of classes, it would obviously consume a little more memory (even if it is a few bytes more or whatever). as you can tell, im one of those guys who is critical of memory and perf together. OK how exactly would I create/store this cache? I mean should it be a static dictionary or should it be placed in a proper caching engine. The downside of the caching engine would be more maintainence and management to be done (i.e using ASP.NET Caching). It also has to be MT safe

Comment: If you're making something like a library, you should cache your reflection cache inside you library. I would go with a static dictionary, MT safe, of course. The downside is that it will keep growing on size as types are reflected, even if they are not used anymore. So, you can write a cache class that wraps the dictionay and manages the expiration of the items. But if you dont mind about the expiration, its quite simpler

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this! I will also use a concurrent dictionary I think. Lets see how it goes and will post back later if I dont see an improvement or its been made worse (which i doubt)